# Jedis pool is initialised multiple times

Tags: java, redis, pool, jedis

I'm using `redis` with the help of `jedis` client. Attaching the code snippet for key value set/get here. Here I'm expecting my `jedisPool` to get initialised only once but it is getting initialised multiple times. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Scratching my head for several days with it. I have no clues why it does multiple initialisation.

```
//$Id$
package experiments.with.truth;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

public class RedisClientUtil {

    private static JedisPool pool;                  //I persume the deafult value initialised in my static variable would be null
    static int maxActiveConnections = 8;
    static int maxWaitInMillis = 2000;
    static String host = "127.0.0.1";
    static int port = 6379;
    static int REDIS_DB = 1;

    public static void initRedisClient() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class classObj = Class.forName("redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool");
            if (classObj != null && pool == null) {
                JedisPoolConfig jedisConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
                jedisConfig.setMaxTotal(maxActiveConnections);
                jedisConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWaitInMillis);
                pool = new JedisPool(jedisConfig, host, port);      

                System.out.println("Pool initialised successfully !");
            }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't initialize redis due to unavailability of jedis jar in your machine. Exception : " + ex);
        }
    }
    public Jedis getJedisConnection() {
        if(pool == null) {
            initRedisClient();
        }
        return pool.getResource();
    }
    private static void returnJedis(Jedis jedis) {
        try {
            pool.returnResource(jedis);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String getValue(String key) throws Exception{
        Jedis jedisCon = null; 
        try {
            jedisCon = getJedisConnection();
            jedisCon.select(REDIS_DB);

            String val = jedisCon.get(key); 
            return val;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jedisCon != null) {
                returnJedis(jedisCon);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void addValueToRedis(String key, String value) {
        Jedis jedisCon = null; 
        try {
            jedisCon = getJedisConnection();
            jedisCon.select(REDIS_DB);

            jedisCon.set(key, value); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jedisCon != null) {
                returnJedis(jedisCon);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Value : " + getValue("a"));
        System.out.println("Value : " + getValue("b"));
        System.out.println("Value : " + getValue("c"));
    }
}
```

I could see this debug log `Pool initialised successfully` multiple times when my program runs. Can someone help me find the loophole in this? Or how could I make this better (or make to behave it as expected) by initialising only once throughout the entire program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a basic multithreading case. Your app asks for 5 connections in a short time. All of them see that pool==null and proceed initializing it.

Easy solution: `public static synchronized void initRedisClient() throws Exception {`

**update** and `private static volatile JedisPool pool;` otherwise you may get null pointer exception.

For more complex and performant solutions search 'efficient lazy singletor in java', which will most probably lead you to `Enum` solution.

Comment: I thought it to be a multi thread issue - but this happened at various intervals..

Comment: This is what is observable from the code you've shown. Various intervals is how much exactly?

Comment: Like one at 12:00 PM and another one at 4:00 PM.

Comment: Try this VM param: `-XX:-TraceClassUnloading`. Maybe your app is thight on memory and unloads some unused classes. And then loads again, which leads to initializing the pool again.

Comment: Oh ! I guessed this could have happened but I was not sure. I assumed since the methods were `public static` they would remain in memory for ever (ie; till the server gets restarted)

Comment: Also the despite you not observing multithreading problems, they do exist in this code. Pool is not final and might not be properly initialized when other thread observes non-null value. And possibility for multiple simultaneous initializations are obvious here. You may add `System.out.println(pool.hashCode())` and see that it might be different.

Comment: I haven't made it as final because - i would try reinitialising the same when the first time initialisation was not successful -  doing `final` will not allow me to do so..

Comment: @rm-rf yes, I didn't say it should be final. I said that it has consequences.

Comment: How can multi-threading be an issue if only #main function is using it?

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha if `getJedisConnection` is called only from main, it woudn't be an issue. However, the existence of a pool here hints that OP plans to use some threading later. Otherwise just remove the pool completely and make a persistent connection.

Comment: I'm not only invoking it from `main` rather invoking it from multiple places across my project @ObiWan-PallavJha

Comment: @Imaskar : I'm just asking - if multiple initialisation on the pool is due to unloading and reloading of class - they is there any way so that i could maintain the `pool` variable in memory for ever (ie' till the process gets restarted) ?

Comment: @rm-rf keep a reference to an instance of RedisClientUtil somwhere